# Azure CosmosDB (SQL API) slow with Azure .Net Core Web App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

A .Net Core Web App, connect with Cosmos DB using SQL API, if running it on Azure as a Web App, a query takes more than 30ms, however, if running the same web app on a Windows 10 PC, connect to the same CosmosDB, same query takes 10~11ms.

If connect to Cosmos DB using Mongo API, then performance looks better, a query takes 5~6ms if running on Azure.

I'd like to know why there's such a big performance difference between SQL API and Mongo API? Is there any thing I need to pay attention on to make performance better? Thanks.

Comment: Is your Azure Web App in the same region as the Cosmos DB account?

Comment: Yes, Cosmos DB, Azure Web App and Windows 10 PC are all at the same region.